# Same width as height css

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to create a web app using AngularJS, but when I'm trying to represent the same width as the height It doesn't work.

HTML CODE:

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left">
   <div id="controlPanel">
       <img src="" class="avatarImage">
   </div>
</md-sidenav>
```

CSS CODE:

```
div#controlPanel {
   width: 100%;
   height: 30%;
   background-color: #333333;
}

img.avatarImage {
   border: 1px red solid;
   width: -----> SAME AS THE WIDTH <-----;
   height: 75%;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Here is the result:
[IMAGE CLICK HERE: I want a square but putting vh or vw doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H55sX.png)

Thank you for reading this and I hope we have a nice answer!

Comment: Did you probably mean, "SAME AS THE *HEIGHT*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [`vh` units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#vh). Per that doc:

> **vh**
>   1/100th of the height of the viewport.

```
height:75%;
width:75vh;
```

Comment: How does this help at all?

Comment: @connexo Well, I'm answering OP's question, right? Maybe I have missed something?

Comment: But this is not working because it puts the width of all the display and not of the div.